# How to set specific scale for leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to create a solution using leaflet.js to display plans and drawings rather then maps. The basic functionality it all set, but it would be great to a scale to the display.

I looked at this solution on github - https://github.com/nerik/leaflet-graphicscale - and it works great. But my question is, how can I adjust the scale to my actual map. Like how do the dimensions of the plan relate to the scale.

Here is an example of how I currently implement the map:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <div id="img1" class="leafletContainer" style=""></div>
</div>

<script>
var imgWidth = 17732;
var imgHeight = 13632;

// create Map
var map = L.map('img1', {
    maxZoom: 8,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
}).setView(new L.LatLng(0,0), 0);

var minimap1 = new Object();
var minimap_loaded = false;

var southWest = map.unproject([0, imgHeight], map.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([imgWidth, 0], map.getMaxZoom());
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var image1 = {
    url :   'zoomifyTiles/hercules2/',
    width  : imgWidth,
    height : imgHeight
}

L.tileLayer.zoomify(image1.url, {
    width: image1.width,
    height: image1.height,
    tolerance: 0.7,             // initial zoom level
}).addTo(map);

var graphicScale = L.control.graphicScale({
    fill: 'fill',
    showSubunits: true,
    minUnitWidth: 30,
    maxUnitsWidth: 240,
    labelPlacement: 'auto'
}).addTo(map);

// Create Minimap
image1mini = L.tileLayer.zoomify(image1.url, {
    width: image1.width,
    height: image1.height,
    tolerance: 0.8,
    attribution: image1.credit
});

// load the mini map if it already isn't loaded
if(minimap_loaded == true) {
    minimap1.changeLayer(image1mini);
} else {
    minimap1 = new L.Control.MiniMap(image1mini, {zoomLevelOffset: -5, toggleDisplay: true}).addTo(map);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Like how do the dimensions of the plan relate to the scale.

In `L.CRS.Simple`, one screen pixel equals one map unit at zoom level 0; In a generalized way, one map unit equals 2<sup>zoomlevel</sup> screen pixels.

Note that if you run things like `map.unproject`, you will lose control over coordinates. Read the [tutorial on `L.CRS.Simple`](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) for tips on how to manage coordinates in these kinds of non-geographical maps.

Comment: Thank you for the input @ivansanchez - I'll take a look at the tutorial.

Comment: Wonder if there was solution that ever came about here?